# Удалить неиспользуемые ресурсы в андроид проекте Intellij Idea

Tags: android, java, intellij-idea

Добрый день. Есть ли возможность в Intellij IDEA 13.1 в андроид проекте найти и удалить неиспользуемые ресурсы? В файлах dimens.xml, strings.xml, color.xml. К примеру в dimens.xml 500 ресурсов, и некоторые из них неиспользуются. Они никак не подсвечиваются, хотелось бы избавиться от них.

Answer (score 4):

[image]